# PHP Web Application: mysql database design best practices question

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I am currently in a debate with a coworker about the best practices concerning the database design of a PHP web application we're creating.  The application is designed for businesses, and each company that signs up will have multiple users using the application.

My design methodology is to create a new database for every company that signs up.  This way everything is sand-boxed, modular, and small.  My coworkers philosophy is to put everyone into one database.  His argument is that if we have 1000+ companies sign up, we wind up with 1000+ databases to deal with.  Not to mention the mess that doing Business Intelligence becomes.

For the sake of example, assume that the application is an order entry system.  With separate databases, table size can remain manageable even if each company is doing 100+ orders a day.  In a single-bucket application, tables can get very big very quickly.

Is there a best practice for this?  I tried hunting around the web, but haven't had much success.  Links, whitepapers, and presentations welcome.

Thanks in advance,

The1Rob

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I talked to the database architect from wordpress.com, the hosting service for WordPress.  He said that they started out with one database, hosting all customers together.  The content of a single blog site really isn't that much, after all.  It stands to reason that a single database is more manageable.

This did work well for them until they got hundreds and thousands of customers, they realized that they needed to **scale out**, running multiple physical servers and hosting a subset of their customers on each server.  When they add a server, it would be easy to migrate individual customers to the new server, but harder to separate data within a single database that belongs to an individual customer's blog.

As customers come and go, and some customers' blogs have high-volume activity while others go stale, the rebalancing over multiple servers becomes an even more complex maintenance job.  Monitoring size and activity per individual database is easier too.

Likewise doing a database **backup or restore** of a single database containing terrabytes of data, versus individual database backups and restores of a few megabytes each, is an important factor.  Consider: a customer calls and says their data got SNAFU'd due to some bad data entry, and could you please restore the data from yesterday's backup?  How would you restore *one* customer's data if all your customers share a single database?

Eventually they decided that splitting into a **separate database per customer**, though complex to manage, offered them greater flexibility and they re-architected their hosting service to this model.

So, while from a *data modeling* perspective it seems like the right thing to do to keep everything in a single database, some *database administration* tasks become easier as you pass a certain breakpoint of data volume.

Comment: Data partitioning (by means of partition table rules) is, possibly, another option as well, though even more complicated to manage sometimes. And, to get those against using multiple database, you DO know this doens't affect reporting at all right? One can easily union/join the appropriate tables across databases and even create cross database views that compile all the reporting data you could ever need.

Answer (score 2):

I would never create a new database for each company. If you want a modular design, you can create this using tables and properly connected primary and secondary keys. This is where i learned about [database normalization](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html) and I'm sure it will help you out here.

This is the method I would use. [SQL Article](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to agree with your co-worker. Relational databases are designed to handle large amounts of data, and the numbers you're talking about (1000+ companies, multiple users per company, 100+ orders/day) are well within the expected bounds. Separate databases means:

- multiple database connections in each script (memory and speed penalty)
- maintenance is harder (DB systems generally do not provide tools for acting on databases as a group) so schema changes, backups, and similar tasks will be more difficult
- harder to run queries on data from multiple companies

If your site becomes huge, you may eventually need to distribute your data across multiple servers. **Deal with that when it happens.** To start out that way for performance reasons sounds like premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally dealt with this situation, but I would think that if you want to do business intelligence, you should aggregate the data into an offline database that you can then run any analysis you want on.

Also, keeping them in separate databases makes it easier to partition across servers (which you will likely have to do if you have 1000+ customers) without resorting to messy replication technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question a while back and came to the conclusion that a single database is drastically more manageable. Right now, we have multiple databases (around 10) and it is already becoming a pain to manage especially when we upgrade the code. We have to migrate every single database.

The upside is that the data is segregated cleanly. Due to the sensitivity of our data, this is a good thing, but it does make it quite a bit more difficult to keep up with.

Answer (score 0):

The separate database methodology has a very big advance over the other:
+ You could broke it up into smaller groups, this architecture scales much better.
+ You could make stand alone servers in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how likely your schemas are to change. If they ever have to change, will you be able to safely make those changes to 1000 separate databases? If a scalability problem is found with your design, how are you going to fix it for 1000 databases?

Answer (score 0):

We run a SaaS (Software-as-a-Service) business with a large number of customers and have elected to keep all customers in the same database.  Managing 1000's of separate databases is an operational nightmare.

You do have to be very diligent creating your data model and the business objects / reporting queries that access them.  One approach you may want to consider is to carry the company ID in every table and ensure that every WHERE clause includes the company ID for the currently logged-in user.  If you use a data access layer, you can enforce that condition there.

As you grow large, you can still vertically partition by placing groups of companies on each physical server, e.g. the first 100 companies on Server A, the next 100 companies on Server B.